# Confusion about dual spaces and convex conjugates

Tags: linear-transformations, convex-analysis, dual-spaces

I am struggeling to understand the definition for the convex conjugate as stated by wiki:
Let $X$ be a real topologacl vector space, and let $X^*$ be the dual space to $X$. Denote the dual pairing by
$$\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle : X^* \times X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}.
$$

For a function
$$f : X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \{ -\infty, \infty \}$$
the convex conjugate
$$f^*: X^*\longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \{ -\infty, \infty \} $$
is defined in terms of the supremum by
$$ f^*(x^*) := \sup\{\langle x^*, x \rangle - f(x) \ | \ x \in X \} .$$

From what I can gather, the dual space to $X$ consists of all $\textit{linear functionals}$ $X \mapsto \mathbb{R}$. However, I fail to see how this applies to the definiton given above.

If we took $X = \mathbb{R^2}$, a linear functional on $\mathbb{R}^2$ would be $\varphi_{y}(x) = \langle x, y\rangle$. This makes it seem like the elements from $X^*$ above are rather elements which make $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ a linear functional. It does not seem to me like
$$f^*(\varphi_y) = \sup\{\langle \varphi_y, x\rangle - f(x)\ | \ x \in \mathbb{R^2} \} $$ for some $y \in \mathbb{R}^2$ makes much sense.

Is there something about the definition of dual spaces I have misunderstood? Or should this be understood as $X^*$ is the space of all $y$ such that $\langle  y, \cdot \rangle$  is a linear functional on $X$?

Comment: I think what is actually confusing you is the use of the same notation for inner product as for the dual pairing. For example if you have a real Hilbert space $H$ and $x \in H$, $y \mapsto \langle x,y \rangle$ is a linear functional on $H$, where $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is the inner product notation. If we denote that functional by $\varphi_x$, then an evaluation in dual pairing notation looks like $\langle \varphi_x,y \rangle$. These brackets aren't exactly the same kind of bracket, even though they are closely related when you're looking at Hilbert spaces.

Comment: That being said, yes, actually, if $y$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f$ is say a continuously differentiable real valued function, then there is absolutely geometric significance to $\sup \{ \langle \phi_y,\rangle x - f(x) : x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \}$. To see how that's possible, notice that the gradient of the inside is $y - \nabla f$, so if the supremum is finite then it is attained at a point where $\nabla f = y$.

Comment: Typo in my second comment...too lazy to fix it.